# Doing simple math on the command line using bash functions: $1 divided by $2 (using bc perhaps)

Tags: command-line, function, arithmetic, bashrc, bc

Sometimes I need to divide one number by another. It would be great if I could just define a bash function for this. So far, I am forced to use expressions like

```
echo 'scale=25;65320/670' | bc
```

but it would be great if I could define a .bashrc function that looked like

```
divide () {
  bc -d $1 / $2
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I have a handy bash function called `calc`:

```
calc () {
    bc -l <<< "$@"
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ calc 65320/670
97.49253731343283582089

$ calc 65320*670
43764400
```

You can change this to suit yourself. For example:

```
divide() {
    bc -l <<< "$1/$2"
}
```

**Note:** `<<<` is a [here string](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) which is fed into the stdin of `bc`. You don't need to invoke `echo`.

Comment: I agree it's looking better without the additional echo thrown in, but since it's a shell builtin, it comes with little to no additional cost. What keeps me from using '<<<' in shell functions is its limitation to bash, while the additional echo allows using it in the original bourne shell or ksh without changes.

Comment: @TatjanaHeuser `ksh`, the 93-variant, supports here-strings.

Comment: To assign to a variable, I did this: 
    foo=$(bc -l <<< "( 2 * 5 ) + 5")

Answer (score 20):

Bash can do the math itself to some extent.  It's not useful for accuracy, though, as it rounds.

```
[user]$ echo $(( 10/5 ))
2
```

But you're exactly right - a bash function would be a simple shortcut and your example basically works.

```
divide() {
  echo "scale=25;$1/$2" | bc
}
```

Throw that in your .bashrc and then you can:

```
[user]$ divide 10 5
2.0000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: `echo $((10 / 5))` needs no quotation.

Comment: Significant annoyance:  `echo $((6383/7671))`  will give you zero. You need to be explicit about floating point numbers: `echo $((6383.0/7671.0)) `

Answer (score 10):

You probably know the bash builtin 'expr' as in

```
$ expr 60 / 5
12
```

which is limited to integers and needs the spaces between the arguments.

What is keeping you from defining a function along the lines of the echo expression you're already using? I.e.

```
 divide () {
   echo $1/$2 | bc
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

Not really an answer to this precise question, but it might be good to know. Use `zsh` ;-)

```
% echo $((65320./670))
97.492537313432834
```

Comment: I was actually looking for this question because I changed to zsh and couldn't use bash's `expr` builtin, so good answer regardless :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `calc` installed on your system and you don't like rounding, you can:

```
div() { calc "$1 / $2"; }
```

Comment: hmm... couldn't find any debian package for 'calc'

Comment: The package is called `apcalc`  (Arbitary Precision)... The binary is called `calc`

Comment: @Peter.O Ok, in the Arch Linux repos it's called [`calc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/).

Answer (score 2):

A dirty hack for small values and a limited precision without using bc would be, to multiply the nominator before division, to get an accurate result.

Example without precision:

```
echo $((13/7)) 
1
```

and with 2 digits precision: multiply by 100 and move the decimal point 2 steps to the left:

```
echo $((100*13/7)) | sed 's/..$/.&/'
1.85
echo $((100*13/7))%
185%
```

This is only useful if the range of numbers is known before, and the precision is always the same. Avoiding to call *bc*, and calling *sed* seems not very reasonable.

Note, that multiplying the values might lead to overflow errors, but not very early:

```
echo $((1000000000*12345678901))
-6101065172709551616
```

Comment: Using double parentheses to evaluate math expressions is deprecated.  Use: `$[expression]` instead

Comment: @laebshade: I can prove you wrong, the opposite is true. Here is a citation of the bash manual: `The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.`

Comment: Also discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81599/80216 "Why should I use $[ EXPR ] instead of $(( EXPR ))?"), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41081417/3960947 "difference between $[a-b] and $((a-b)) in bash") and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2415724/3960947 "bash: $[<arithmetic-expression>] vs. $((<arithmetic-expression>))").

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bc, you could use awk:

```
div() { awk -v p=$1 -v q=$2 'BEGIN{print p/q}'; }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
echo Division
efgh=$num1/$num2
remainder=$num1%num2
echo $num1 "/" $num2 "=" $efgh.$remainder
echo
```