# Example for adding

Tags: bash

**Example 1.**

Adding to the console works well

```
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ a="$(date +%s)"
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ b="$(date +%s)"
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ echo $[a+b]
2844184057
pic@pic:~/Desktop$
```

**Example 2.**

It's the same, but the script

```
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ cat a.sh 
#!bin/bash

a="$(date +%s)"
b="$(date +%s)"

echo $[a+b]pic@pic:~/Desktop$ sh a.sh 
$[a+b]
pic@pic:~/Desktop$
```

Why do I get a different result? How to get the same result?

**EDIT:**

```
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ ls -l $(command -v sh)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 sty 10  2014 /bin/sh -> dash
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ ./a.sh
bash: ./a.sh: Brak dostępu
pic@pic:~/Desktop$
```

**EDIT -1 :**

It works like a run so

```
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ . ./a.sh
2844188704
pic@pic:~/Desktop$
```

**EDIT -2 :**

Does not work

```
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ chmod +x a.sh
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ ./a.sh
bash: ./a.sh: bin/bash: zły interpreter: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
pic@pic:~/Desktop$
```

**EDIT -3 :**

Corrected

```
pic@pic:~/Desktop$ cat a.sh 
#!/bin/bash

a="$(date +%s)"
b="$(date +%s)"

echo $[a+b]pic@pic:~/Desktop$ ./a.sh
2844189920
pic@pic:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: You should run your script with `./a.sh` not with `sh a.sh`. `sh` is (or at least could be) a different shell than `bash` and in your case apparently does not understand `$[a+b]` syntax. Check which shell `sh` is linked to with `ls -l $(command -v sh)`.

Comment: if `a.sh` is executable (**x** in `ls -l`) do `./a.sh` if not do `. ./a.sh`

Comment: FWIW, according to the bash man: "The format for arithmetic expansion is: `$((expression))` The old format `$[expression]` is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash."

Comment: Your shebang line reads `#!bin/bash` that should be `#!/bin/bash`. It is unlikely that you have bash in the subdirectory `bin` of the current directory. And because of that you are using `sh` (`dash` ?) on your system in the script

Comment: Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81599/why-should-i-use-expr-instead-of-expr and its links for more info on `$((expression))` vs `$[expression]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script is missing the correct header, your shebang line reads

```
#!bin/bash
```

that should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It is unlikely that you have bash in the subdirectory bin of the current directory. And because of that you are using sh (dash ?) on your system in the script