# Help regarding a Bash script exercise

Tags: shell-script

Greetings dear community, I would love your assistance regarding this small bash-based exercise. I have completed the exercise but I am not sure if it is entirely correct. Kindly advise for any improvements or possible errors.

Exercise:

1. Create a directory called `Exam` and enter this directory.
2. While in the `Exam` directory, create a file called `sc1`.
3. Open the `sc1` file and write a bash script that will - "Using the while loop, create four files (ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4) in the `/home/student/Desktop/` Directory.
4. Copy these files into the `/home/student/Exam/` Directory.
5. Check/Verify if we have the permissions to run the `ex1` file.
6. Rename the `ex2` file and name it `log`.

Answers :

1. `mkdir /home/student/Exam/` + `cd /home/student/Exam`
2. `touch sc1`
3. We should type `vim sc1` and then type the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash 
   while dir /home/student/Desktop/; do  
      touch "$dir/ex1"
      touch "$dir/ex2"
      touch "$dir/ex3"
      touch "$dir/ex4"
   done
   ```
4. `cp -a /home/student/Desktop/. /home/student/Exam/`
5. `ls -l ex1` (Corrected)
6. `mv ex2 log` (Corrected)

Comment: I don't really see the use for the `while` loop here (you could just use `touch /home/student/Desktop/ex{1..4}`), and it's unclear _which_ `ex2` file should be renamed (at that point there should be two of them).

Comment: The one that was coped to /home/student/Exam/. It is a template exercise, it does not make much sense. My lecturer wants me to get better in scripts :D that's why the while loop is there.

Comment: The last command must be `mv ex2 log`

Comment: Thank you and what do you think of the script? Is it correctly written?

Comment: *"Is it correctly written?"* Did you try it? Does it work ;) ?

Comment: #!/bin/bash 
while dir /home/student/Desktop/; do  
   touch "$dir/ex1"
   touch "$dir/ex2"
   touch "$dir/ex3"
   touch "$dir/ex4"
done  - It should work, but it keeps giving me permission denied cannot touch '/ex1' and the same goes for other three.

Comment: Your #5 is listing the wrong file, should be `ls -l ex1` based on exercise instructions

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: *"It should work"* no, it shouldn't. In `while dir /home/student/Desktop/` you run the *command* `dir` on file `/home/student/Desktop/`. By chance, `dir` is a valid command and returns a zero exit status if the file exists - so the body of the `while` loop gets executed. However `/home/student/Desktop/` does not get assigned to the *variable* `dir` as you seem to be expecting. You can't just substitute `while [BOOLEAN]; do` in place of `for word in [LIST]; do` in the way you are trying. (A `for` loop would make much more sense in this context - which is perhaps why you are getting confused.)

Comment: Also, are you sure you need to check that `ex1` is executable? Don't you mean you need to check that `sc1` is executable?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nowhere does it say that the script you write should ever be executed. The three last steps are void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a directory called Exam and enter this directory.

   `mkdir Exam && cd Exam`
2. While in the Exam directory, create a file called sc1.

   `touch sc1`
3. Open the sc1 file and write a bash script that will - "Using the while loop, create four files (ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4) in the /home/student/Desktop/ Directory.

   See the first example [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html)
   Create a variable called `i` and assign it 1, then start looping, and do it while `i` isn't lower than 5 (lower than means until 4) - or you could use `-le 4` for lower or equal 4. Add 1 to the last i value before next iteration.

```
i="1"

while [ $i -lt 5 ]
do
  touch "ex$i"
  i=$[$i+1] 
done
```

4. Copy these files into the /home/student/Exam/ Directory.

   `cp ex* /home/student/Exam/`
5. Check/Verify if we have the permissions to run the ex1 file.

   Check by tunning `ls -l /home/student/Exam/ex1`

   Fix by running  `chmod 700 /home/student/Exam/ex1`
6. Rename the ex2 file and name it log.

   `mv /home/student/Exam/ex2 /home/student/Exam/log`

Comment: Upvoted - but note that `i=$[$i+1]` is deprecated. See for example [Why should I use $\[ EXPR \] instead of $(( EXPR ))?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81599/why-should-i-use-expr-instead-of-expr)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: No worries Michael, don't forget to select an answer you find useful to your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
i=1
while (( i <= 4 ))
do
   echo "ex$(( i++ ))"
done
```

This is the "nicest" while loop I can make. A for loop can take all three expressions:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ))
do
   echo "ex$i"
done
```

---

Or like this, avoiding the (( double parens ))  altogether.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
   echo "ex$i"
done
```

This is a in-between solution: it is easier to say "1,2,3,4" than "from 1 to 4".

But `touch "ex1"; touch "ex2"; touch "ex3" ...` is not a good idea in general - and in particular if you are told to use a loop. Being lazy is important, but a programmer must also be too proud to copy paste (more than once).

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
   touch "/home/student/Desktop/ex$i"
done
```

This should be the complete loop. If ever you need more or different numbers (or letters/strings), you can easily change it.

And since we have left the while loop anyway, let me add the shortest kind of "loop", brace expansion:

`touch /home/student/Desktop/ex{1,2,3,4}`

or

```
dir=/home/student/Desktop
touch $dir/ex{1..4}
```

---

```
Tell me master can you answer a question:
Is it the fingers or the brain that you're teaching a lesson? 
                                       (White Stripes)
```